# C#: calling a button event handler method without actually clicking the button

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, event-handling

I have a button in my aspx file called btnTest. The .cs file has a function which is called when the button is clicked.

```
btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

How can I call this function from within my code (i.e. without actually clicking the button)?

Answer (score 31):

```
btnTest_Click(null, null);
```

Provided that the method isn't using either of these parameters (it's very common not to.)

To be honest though this is icky. If you have code that needs to be called you should follow the following convention:

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SomeSub();
}

protected void SomeOtherFunctionThatNeedsToCallTheCode()
{
   SomeSub();
}

protected void SomeSub()
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: No. Not too much code. You shouldn't use a method both for a call and an event. It's misleading and confusing.

Comment: Where do you put exception handling? In all three methods? Why create methods just to call a single method? Not confusing. Buttton_Click(null, null) is obvious. SomeOtherFunctionThatNeedsToCallTheCode makes no sense to me.

Comment: I was using that function name as an example. I could have easily put `foo()` instead.

Comment: As far as the exception handling that depends on a lot of factors that extend well beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference what you call these other methods. By adding the extra code, you know have to think about it, manage it, and handle any errors this extra code can produce. It is a simple method call, and the name of the method is nearly self-documenting.

Comment: No it's not self-documented. That's the point. If btnTest_Click is fired at times when btnTest has not been clicked that's misleading. Period.

Comment: You know btnTest_Click is not fired because sender is not the button or is null. That is the whole purpose of sender. My point is people write too much code. This is not a button click event. It is just a simple method call.

Comment: "Period?" It is just a discussion, not an argument.

Comment: "nearly self-documenting". Adding a comment such as "calling method to avoid creating extra methods" goes a long way.

Comment: There is no discussion. Having btnTest_Click execute when btnTest has not been clicked is misleading.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Button.PerformClick()

Comment: Every language is capable of doing all sorts of nasty things. Doesn't mean you should. :)

Comment: Siding with Spencer here, SomeSub is a separation of concerns.  Spencer isn't advocating calling it `SomeSub`, but probably more `HandleUserLogin`.  It's a lot more obvious to maintenance developers to see: `HandleUserLogin ();` than `btnLogin_Click (null, null)`, especially if `btnLogin_Click` does more than just handle the user's login!

Comment: "My point is people write too much code". Less code is not always better. In this case i have to agree with @SpencerRuport.

Answer (score 19):

Use

```
btnTest_Click( this, new EventArgs() );
```

Comment: EventArgs.Empty is static of new EventArgs(). So EventArgs.Empty is more appropriate, but creating new is nearly as good.

Answer (score 6):

All above methods are not good because you might change event function name. The easiest is:

```
btnTest.PerfromClick();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use reflection to Invoke the `OnClick` method which will fire the click event handlers.

I feel dirty posting this but it works...

```
MethodInfo clickMethodInfo = typeof(Button).GetMethod("OnClick", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

clickMethodInfo.Invoke(buttonToInvoke, new object[] { EventArgs.Empty });
```

Answer (score 4):

If the method isn't using either `sender` or `e` you *could* call:

```
btnTest_Click(null, null);
```

What you probably should consider doing is extracting the code from within that method into its own method, which you could call from both the button click event handler, and any other places in code that the functionality is required.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a method on your form, you can call it just like any other method.  You just have to create an EventArgs object to pass to it, (and pass it the handle of the button as `sender`)

Answer (score 2):

Simply call:

```
btnTest_Click(null, null);
```

Just make sure you aren't trying to use either of those params in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Inside first button event call second button(imagebutton) event:

```
imagebutton_Click((ImageButton)this.divXXX.FindControl("imagbutton"), EventArgs.Empty);
```

you can use the button state such as the imagebutton's commandArgument if you save something into it.

Answer (score 0):

btnTest_Click(new object(), EventArgs.Empty)

Comment: passing a generic object seems like a bad idea. better to pass the button or null.

Comment: @John Why do you feel that way?

Comment: because the sender is normally the control, so if the click handler uses it at all, it will expect that `sender as Control` will work.

Comment: `(sender as Control)` will return null if you pass in an Object, so that argument doesn't work. My counter argument is that by passing in a null, you break code that uses `(sender.GetType)` to check the type.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the btnTest_Click just like any other function.

The most basic form would be this:

```
btnTest_Click(this, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btnSubmit_Click(btnSubmit,EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21276072)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass parameter `sender` and `e` to call button event handler in .cs file

```
btnTest_Click(sender,e);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
btnTest.Click +=new EventHandler(btnTest_Click)
```