# programmatically click a button vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a hidden button on my page which fires a jquery function, seen as though i cant call the jquery function from the server side im trying to fire the button click on a asp button and i am wondering how i would do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify, you want jquery to trigger a postback event to the server?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you want to do, but here are a couple of options:

For simulating a click on an HTML button (clientside), you could use JQuery:

```
$("#mybutton).click();
```

or

```
$("#mybutton).trigger("click");
```

Of course you'll need to attach the handler to the button in your

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mybutton").click(function(){
        //do something
    });
});
```

If you want to simulate a click on an ASP.Net (serverside button):

You can simulate a button being clicked by calling the function the button's `Click` event is bound to:

```
<asp:button runat="server" id="btn1" Onclick="btn1_Click" Text="Click Me" />

protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //stuff that happens when you click the button.
}
```

and then in code:

e.g.

```
btn1_Click(null, new EventArgs());
```

Responses to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390439/c-calling-a-button-event-handler-method-without-actually-clicking-the-button) go into more depth on this subject.

UPDATE:

From the serverside the best you could do is reload the page and then get it to generate a script to make the necessary function calls.

Does the button have to be an  or can it be a regular HTML button? If the latter just wire it up to a function that makes the call to modal by its Id.

If the former, you'll need to add a CssClass to the declaration and wire it up to a function via its class - 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".myButtonClass").click(function(){//Wired-up by class
        $("#myButtonId").click(function(){//Wired-up by html ID
            $('#MyModalContent').modal();
            return false;
            //you might need extra code to prevent the event propogating.
    });

Comment: ok so when the button clicks it fires <asp:Button ID="Button2"  runat="server" class="osx" Text="Click" /> which then display a popup window i cant think of a way to fire this jquery from the server side so i was trying to mimic the server firing the button but also because i have a formRewriter which enables me to do things like Default.aspx?Profile=PROFILEID which fires every time any post back is done then i dont think what im trying to do is possible :/

Comment: if you want to display an alert box (client side) you should just wire up the client-side event of the HTML button with Jquery or vanilla JS. 

If you can post some markup it will make it easier for us StackOverflowers to understand your requirements.

Comment: the popup box is one used here http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/ it is the osx style i want to be able to fire the popup from the server side

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [WatiN](http://watin.org/) framework. It allows browser ui automation easily.

Example:

```
browser.Button(Find.ByName("<buttonname>")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) to call client script from code-behind.

Comment: how can i use this to fire a function that is fired by a buttons class name? ie the buttons class name is OSX and it then fires the jQuery