# How to trigger button through code in devexpress?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, devexpress

This Code Work fine with ordinary button but the button in devexpress provided me some error.
It says that sender and e are not declared..

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
    Select Case keyData
        Case Keys.Enter
              btnPayment_Click(sender, e)
        Case Keys.F2

        Case Keys.F5


        Case Keys.F6


        Case Keys.Escape
            Me.Close()

        Case Else
            Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Select

    Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB 2010, I have used the PerformClick. Will that work for you? ex. btnPayment.PerfformClick()

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call the btnPayment_Click handler by passing it two variables which are not declared (sender, e).

If you merely want the code in btnPayment_Click to execute and *it does not depend on the sender parameter or the e parameter* then you still need to pass something - ie:

```
btnPayment_Click(null, null)
```

A better structure might be something like this :

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SomeSub();
}

protected void SomeOtherFunctionThatNeedsToCallTheCode()
{
   SomeSub();
}

protected void SomeSub()
{
   // ...
}
```

see :  [C#: calling a button event handler method without actually clicking the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390439/c-calling-a-button-event-handler-method-without-actually-clicking-the-button)